# Ordenar imagenes con CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo con bootstrap un portfolio de imagenes. Necesito eliminar el espacio que existe entre filas, quiero que las fotos solo esten separadas por un margen independientemenete si es horizontal o vertical.

Este es mi codigo Código editado, donde elimine columnas y filas de Bootstrap pensando que podia solucionarlo.

```css
.fachadas {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 6px;
}

.fachadas-item img{
    border-radius: 8px; 
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="fachadas">
                                        <div class="fachadas-item" style="cursor: pointer;" id="'.$id.'">
                                            <img src="'.$nombre.'" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                        </div>
                                     </div>
```

Así es como se ve........

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como me gustaría que se vea..................

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No olvides mencionar la versión de bootstrap que estás utilizando (puedes hacerlo incluso en las etiquetas). ¿Es necesario que sea con CSS puro? ¿Las utilidades de espaciado de bootstrap (como _gap_) no son suficientes para tus requerimientos?

Comment: Utilizo bootstrap 5. intente solucionarlo con bootstrap pero no pude realizarlo, e intente con CSS y tampo logro eliminar el espaciado entre filas.

Comment: ¿Ni siquiera utilizando _gap-0_ en el div principal (la fila)? ¿Estás utilizando correctamente los rows y columns?

Comment: Nisiquiera... si estoy utilizando bien bootstrap, lo uso a menudo....

Comment: Pregunté lo último ya que el segundo _row_ no tiene ningún _col_. Puedes agregar un [repro] ejecutable en la pregunta misma a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`). Para las imágenes de prueba puedes colocar las generadas en sitios como [dummyimage](https://dummyimage.com/), por ejemplo.

Comment: Editado el post

Comment: Afirmas estar usando bootstrap pero no veo ninguna clase de bootstrap en tu código. Tal como te han mencionado, haz un [mre], pues tal como está tu código no es ejecutable. Si tú no te esfuerzas en darnos las herramientas necesarias para ayudarte, por qué iba a esforzarse nadie en responderte?? Edita la pregunta, añade el [mre] que es muy fácil de hacer para html/css y seguro que podemos ayudarte. De lo contrario, seguramente la pregunta acabe en el pozo de preguntas sin respuesta...

Comment: ¡El estilo _masonry_! Veo que para Bootstrap 5 [se recomienda usar un plugin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/card/#masonry). Entonces, lo que estás buscando no es ordenar imágenes necesariamente, sino que el espaciado entre una y otra sea igual, independientemente del tamaño de cada una. Por cierto, el snippet que agregaste no es un [repro] ejecutable.

Comment: hay muchos ejemplos por ahi, como ya comentaron, el nombre es "Masonry layout"

Answer (score 0):

con CSS Grid, algo nativo de CSS, es posible y sencillo

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  background: #000;
  grid-template-areas:
    'uno dos tres cuatro'
    'uno dos tres cuatro'
    'uno dos tres cuatro'
    'uno dos tres cuatro'
    'cinco dos tres cuatro'
    'cinco dos siete cuatro'
    'cinco seis siete ocho'
    'cinco seis siete ocho'
    'cinco seis siete ocho'
    'cinco seis siete ocho';
  grid-gap: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.cont > div {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.uno {
  grid-area: uno;
}

.dos {
  grid-area: dos;
}

.tres {
  grid-area: tres;
}

.cuatro {
  grid-area: cuatro;
}

.cinco {
  grid-area: cinco;
}

.seis {
  grid-area: seis;
}

.siete {
  grid-area: siete;
}

.ocho {
  grid-area: ocho;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="uno"></div>
  <div class="dos"></div>
  <div class="tres"></div>
  <div class="cuatro"></div>
  <div class="cinco"></div>
  <div class="seis"></div>
  <div class="siete"></div>
  <div class="ocho"></div>
</div>
```

Ya solo es que juegues con las imagenes que tienes y lo adaptes al tamaño de cada DIV

El truco esta en jugar con el 'grid-template-area', puedes moficarlo como quieras

```
grid-template-areas:
'uno dos tres cuatro'
'uno dos tres cuatro'
'uno dos tres cuatro'
'uno dos tres cuatro'
'cinco dos tres cuatro'
'cinco dos siete cuatro'
'cinco seis siete ocho'
'cinco seis siete ocho'
'cinco seis siete ocho'
'cinco seis siete ocho';
```

Aquí tienes mas ejemplos de como se usa:
[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-template-areas.php)
[Docs Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

Comment: Esto suena rebuscado (no mal) y si las imagenes no son exactamente como las mostro? si las carga de un back y no sabe los tamaños??? como definiria en esa caso la grilla?

Answer (score 0):

Para crear una galeria de ese tipo lo más fácil es usar `column-width` y/o `column-count`, lo cual te creará columnas. Si con `column-width` usas una función como `clamp`, `min`, `max`, etc además puedes hacerlo responsivo.

##### Sobre los márgenes

Primero hay que tener cuidado, porque los navegadores tienen CSS predefinido y es muy usual que las imágenes tengan un margen y bordes mayores que cero.

Luego cuando trabajas con columnas puedes usar `column-gap` para añadir un espacio entre columnas y entre filas deberás usar un `margin-bottom`

Demo

```js
//SOLO PARA FINES DE PRUEBA
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

for(let i=0;i<20;i++){
  const img = new Image(getRandom(100,300), getRandom(100,400));
  contenedor.appendChild(img);
}
```

```css
img{
  background-color:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
  border:0;
  margin:0 0 18px 0;
  display:block;
}

#contenedor{
 column-width: clamp(20vw,200px,100vw);
 column-gap: 10px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  
</div>
```